# How do I switch between application windows with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, window-manager

Say I have two windows of a browser running, how can  I switch between those two windows? like <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

will cycle between windows of the current application when using i.a. US keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

- ⌘`: *Move focus to next window* (in application)
- ⌃F4: *Move focus to active or next window* (visible windows on the current space)

(On the U.S. locale and keyboard layout.)

[image]

Comment: +1 The keyboard shortcuts window will provide the correct answer regardless of the keyboard layout.

Comment: Good answer, but a note for others--this won't to change to the other window if that window is full screen. Say, for example, two chrome windows, both full screen.

Answer (score 0):

To have a more complete way of switching between windows in all apps simiilar to the Windows way get a third party application like [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/).

Both of these allow <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will switch between all windows in all apps in a last used order (or can be configured to another order)

Comment: Optimal Layout is dead