# How to switch between browser windows with keyboard?

Tags: shortcut, window-manager, web-browser

For other applications I use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between different application and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>backquote</kbd> to switch between windows of the same application.

But not for browsers.

How to switch between browser windows?

Comment: Do you talk about Cmd-Tab or Ctrl-Tab? And which browser are you using?

Comment: Are the shortcuts enabled in System Preferences (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30143/how-do-i-switch-between-application-windows-with-keyboard-shortcuts?rq=1)?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between browser tabs on both Safari and Firefox.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> will switch between open windows of a browser. However, if your browser windows are full-screen, then just like any other app, that key combination will not work. In that case you have to use the Spaces controls, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>➡️</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>⬅️</kbd>

Comment: The problem is that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> works for all applications (even in full screen mode) except Chrome browser.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean: how do I switch between tabs, the answer is:
Control-Tab or Shift-Command-]